# {"non_field_errors":["Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got Company."]}

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

file company.py(models)

```
from django.db import models

COMPANY_TYPE = [('ИП', 'ИП'), ('АО', 'АО'), ('ТОО', 'ТОО')]


class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=255)
    company_type = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=10, choices=COMPANY_TYPE, default='ИП')
    logo = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=255)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('user.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='companies')
    average_review = models.FloatField(blank=True, default=0, editable=True)
    count_of_review = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0, editable=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, auto_now_add=True)
    last_change_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
class CompanyDetailView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request, company_id):
        data = get_object_or_404(Company, id=company_id)
        payload = CompanyDetailSerializer(data=data)
        payload.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return Response(payload.data)
```

serializers.py

```
class CompanyDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'company_type', 'logo', 'owner', 'average_review', 'count_of_review', 'created_date', 'last_change_date')
```

**But it returns data**

```
{"non_field_errors":["Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got Company."]}
```

I could not find any solutions, I am only started coding in rest framework)

Comment: Since it seems you just need the representation of the model object, you can use `payload = CompanyDetailSerializer(data)` (without `data=`) instead and remove the `is_valid` line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete `payload.is_valid(raise_exception=True)` from your code

We are using it in `POST` & `Update` endpoints to ensure that the request body contains the data that we need to receive

Check out these links for more info [Link1](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) , [Link2](https://github.com/MohamedAliHamza/DoctorOnline/blob/main/user/api/admin/views.py)